# Relationship between view and model in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

In Backbone.js, how does a view know what model it represents?

Is it necessary for the view to be named Model_NameView? Because I can't find any other View property or function for setting the model (like collection has the model property, to define what models this collection is of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see at http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View, there is a `model` property for each view. In other words, you do not have to name the view and model anything in particular.

Comment: it's not listed in the docs anywhere other than the initializer, but it's there. you can call `this.model` anywhere in the view, and it will be the model you passed in. same thing with `this.collection` in a view.